# Lights appear more dominantly in cycles render vs cycles preview

Tags: rendering, lighting

There appears to be a discrepancy between my cycles preview render vs my cycles final render. My final render seems to have far more light present in the overall image than the preview.

I have ensured that there are no hidden lightsources, as evident by the outliner.

What causes this disparity?

Download Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LwarHlkNtoR0_gVgvHzh2hOWPsCkEXu9/view?usp=sharing

**`OUTLINER`**

[image]

**`CYCLES RENDER PREVIEW`**
[image]
**`CYCLES FULL RENDER`**
[image]

Comment: could be a lot of reasons...e.g. compositing, settings in render panel and so on...so yes, please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris link supplied

Comment: @Chris havent fully confirmed yet, but i think theres a good chance its the compositor. im using a youtubers .blend template and some of the template compositing stuff might be affecting the output. im gonna take a closer look now

Comment: i you put the compositing off -> the result is pretty close to the preview ;)

Comment: nice nice, my only question is, how? lol - I made it so the `Group Input` goes DIRECT to the `Group Output` but there is no change in the render result. Render Preview still != Full Render @Chris

Comment: It might have to do with color space settings, check and see if there was any different setting they had in the Color Management section of the Render Panel.

Comment: @Jakemoyo I have played around with color management but none of them cause the resulting render difference

Comment: @Chris would you be able to post an image of the before and after with you changing the compositor? Disabling composite effects seems to have no effect for me...